# Filter what to show in DataGridView vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, dataset, datagridcolumn

I'm trying to get user's projects with ID and title from database, but I only need to show the title of project. In same time, I need the id to be retrievd from database as I need it (2nd question) so that when I click in a button, it will open a new form with all details of selected item from datagrid (As I can't use sql query with where title=title but I have to use ID)

Here is my so simple code which is working but showing ID and title :

```
    Dim DataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, title From project;", MySqlConnection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    DataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Projects")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Projects")
```

Comment: For 2nd question, I found how to get the ID by Dim nbr As String = DGCurrentJob.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString() but not how to transfert it to next form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show only "Title" you may do this ..

```
DataGridView1.Columns("id").Visible = False
```

As your sample  .. assumed you show Form2

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = DGCurrentJob.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value

Form2.TextBox2.Text = DGCurrentJob.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value

Form2.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in my system, it is Columns (with an s). Thank you again :)

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa .. sorry, off the screen .. =) .. it's corrected !

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to not use `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` in the `GridView` markup, but rather use `BoundColumn` or `TemplateColumn` declarations to control what data is visible to the end user, while still having the data available for use (i.e. ID value).